# How to distinguish a Win32 socket handle from other pipe handles?

Tags: winapi, winsock

I need to determine whether a handle that my code did not create, for which `GetFileType()==FILE_TYPE_PIPE`, is a socket or not. There does not seem to be an API for this.

I have tried the following. The general idea is to use a socket-specific function and treat failure as meaning non-socket.

- `getsockopt()` -- This was my first attempt. Unfortunately it seems to hang when called by many threads on the same (non-socket) handle.
- `WSAEnumNetworkEvents()` -- this is what Gnulib does but will have undesirable side effects if the handle *is* a socket.
- `getpeername()` -- this is what cygwin does but this will fail for some sockets too. Guessing whether an error implies socket-ness does not seem reliable and future safe.

I do not mind if the solution only work on some versions of Windows, e.g. Vista, I can always fall back to some other method in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking that perhaps you could attempt to call **GetNamedPipeInfo()** on your handle. If the call succeeds you know that the handle is a pipe handle, otherwise it must be a socket.

Comment: Thanks. This might be safer than using the socket-specific functions   (which have been known to hang for non-sockets).

Comment: GetNamedPipeInfo() may block. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `WSADuplicateSocket`. Then just check `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` to see if it is in fact a named pipe...

Comment: I did not try this because [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaduplicatesocketa) says "The WSADuplicateSocket function cannot be used on a QOS-enabled socket", so it would presumably fail for some sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetNamedPipeHandleState() as well, evaluating the result with GetLastError().

Comment: GetNamedPipeHandleState() may block. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used `getpeername()` but recently a user of our code reported that `getpeername()` seemed to hang. This was surprising, since e.g. [some related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-1-1-blocking-routines-and-einprogress-2) says "Even on a blocking socket, some functions — ... getpeername for example — complete immediately" (which is in the context of actual sockets, and Windows Sockets 1.1, but still).

The problem is if some other thread is already in a blocking call to `ReadFile()` on the same input stream, then `getpeername()` on that input stream will hang.

So, I did an experiment, using the program below. The conclusions, when another thread is already in a blocking `ReadFile()` on the same input handle, are: **(Update: added result for socket handle)**

- `getpeername()` will hang.
- `GetNamedPipeInfo()` will hang. Even worse, in some circumstances it seems to cause the `ReadFile()` to return early, successfully, with zero bytes read.
- `GetNamedPipeHandleState()` with all optional arguments NULL (i.e. not requesting any information about the handle) did not hang in my experiments **but does not fail for sockets**, so it is useless.
- `GetNamedPipeHandleState()` with either optional argument non-NULL (i.e. requesting some information about the handle). Will hang.

So, none of these are able to distinguish between a socket and a pipe in a non-blocking manner.

```
/*

Demonstrate various ways to distinguish between socket and pipe for an
input stream classified as FILE_TYPE_PIPE. Some of them hang if some
other thread is doing a blocking ReadFile() on the same input handle
at the same time.

  cl.exe getpeername_hang.c Ws2_32.lib /MD /Z7 /MD /WX  /W3

In a cmd.exe window (we use "powershell ... | " just to make a pipe as STD_INPUT_HANDLE input for getpeername_hang.exe) :

Test using getpeername(). This hangs.
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep 30}" | .\getpeername_hang.exe getpeername

Test using GetNamedPipeInfo(). This hangs. Note: In cygwin Emacs shell the call to GetNamedPipeInfo() makes ReadFile() return success with zero bytes read, which is really scary.
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep 30}" | .\getpeername_hang.exe getnamedpipeinfo

Test using GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, &state, NULL...). Either optioanal argument non-NULL (lpState or lpCurInstances). This hangs.
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep 30}" | .\getpeername_hang.exe getnamedpipehandlestatea

Test using GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, NULL...). All optional arguments NULL. This does not hang but it does not fail for sockets, so it is useless.
  powershell -nop -c "& {sleep 30}" | .\getpeername_hang.exe getnamedpipehandlestatea_null


*/

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static DWORD WINAPI readingThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
  HANDLE hInput = *(HANDLE*)lpParam;
  CHAR buffer[256];
  DWORD bytesRead;

  // Read from the input (blocking read)
  if (ReadFile(hInput, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytesRead, NULL)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Read %lu bytes from input\n", (unsigned long) bytesRead);
    fflush(stdout);
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "ReadFile failed. Error %lu\n", (unsigned long) GetLastError());
    fflush(stderr);
  }

  return 0;
}

static int isSocketGetpeername(HANDLE h)
{
  SOCKADDR_STORAGE peerAddr;
  int peerAddrLen = (int) sizeof(peerAddr);

  if (getpeername((SOCKET)h, (struct sockaddr*)&peerAddr, &peerAddrLen) == 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Success from getpeername()\n");
    return 1;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "getpeername failed. Error %lu\n", (unsigned long)WSAGetLastError());
    return 0;
  }
}

static int isSocketGetNamedPipeInfo(HANDLE h)
{
  if (GetNamedPipeInfo(h, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Success from GetNamedPipeInfo()\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetNamedPipeInfo() failed. Error %lu\n", (unsigned long)GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }
}

static int isSocketGetNamedPipeHandleStateA_NULL(HANDLE h)
{
  if (GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Success from GetNamedPipeHandleStateA()\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetNamedPipeHandleStateA() failed. Error %lu\n", (unsigned long)GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }
}

static int isSocketGetNamedPipeHandleStateA(HANDLE h)
{
  DWORD dummy;
  // Hangs: GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, &dummy, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
  // Hangs: GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, NULL, &dummy, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
  // Hangs: GetNamedPipeHandleStateW(h, &dummy, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
  // Hangs: GetNamedPipeHandleStateW(h, NULL, &dummy, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)
  if (GetNamedPipeHandleStateA(h, &dummy, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Success from GetNamedPipeHandleStateA()\n");
    return 0;
  } else {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetNamedPipeHandleStateA() failed. Error %lu\n", (unsigned long)GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }
}

static char *getFileType(HANDLE h)
{
  DWORD fileType = GetFileType(h);
  switch (fileType)
    {
    case FILE_TYPE_DISK:
      return "FILE_TYPE_DISK";
    case FILE_TYPE_PIPE:
      return "FILE_TYPE_PIPE";
    case FILE_TYPE_CHAR:
      return "FILE_TYPE_CHAR";
    case  FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
      return "FILE_TYPE_UNKNOWN";
    case FILE_TYPE_REMOTE:
      return "FILE_TYPE_REMOTE";
    default:
      return "GetFileType_IMPOSSIBLE_RESULT";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  HANDLE hInput;
  HANDLE hThread;
  char *how;

  if (argc > 1) {
    how = argv[1];
  } else {
    how = "getpeername";
  }

  // Initialize Winsock
  int foo = 1;
  if (foo) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // Get a handle to the standard input stream
  hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  if (hInput == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get the input handle. Error %lu\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }
  char *fileType = getFileType(hInput);
  fprintf(stdout, "Input is a %s\n", fileType);
  fflush(stdout);

  // Create a thread that reads from the input
  hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, readingThreadFunction, &hInput, 0, NULL);
  if (hThread == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread. Error %lu\n", GetLastError());
    return 1;
  }

  // Wait for a while to ensure readingThreadFunction() starts blocking in ReadFile().
  Sleep(1000);
  // At this point, the readingThreadFunction() should be blocked in ReadFile (and read *hInput)

  if (strcmp(fileType, "FILE_TYPE_PIPE") == 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Using method %s to determine whether input is a socket\n", how);
    fflush(stdout);

    int isSocket;
    ULONGLONG startTick = GetTickCount64();

    if (strcmp("getpeername", how) == 0) {
      isSocket = isSocketGetpeername(hInput);
    } else if (strcmp("getnamedpipeinfo", how) == 0) {
      isSocket = isSocketGetNamedPipeInfo(hInput);
    } else if (strcmp("getnamedpipehandlestatea", how) == 0) {
      isSocket = isSocketGetNamedPipeHandleStateA(hInput);
    } else if (strcmp("getnamedpipehandlestatea_null", how) == 0) {
      isSocket = isSocketGetNamedPipeHandleStateA_NULL(hInput);
    } else {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unknown variant %s\n", how);
      return 1;
    }

    ULONGLONG elapsedSeconds = (GetTickCount64() - startTick) / 1000;
    int did_block = (elapsedSeconds > 5); // plenty

    if (isSocket) {
      fprintf(stdout, "Input is a socket %s\n", (did_block ? "BLOCKED" : "(quickly determined)"));
    } else {
      fprintf(stdout, "Input is NOT a socket %s\n", (did_block ? "BLOCKED" : "(quickly determined)"));
    }
  } else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Input is neither a pipe nor a socket (%s)\n", fileType);
  }
  fflush(stdout);

  int sleep_before_exit = 1;
  if (sleep_before_exit) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Sleeping a while before exiting\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    Sleep(5000);
  }

  int do_proper_cleanup = 1;
  if (do_proper_cleanup) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Wait for ReadFile()-thread to exit\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    WSACleanup();
  } else {
    (void)CancelSynchronousIo(hThread);
  }

  fprintf(stdout, "Successful exit\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  return 0;
}
```